# Generate zip of polymer app without all the non-production files

Tags: javascript, polymer, bower

If you set up a Polymer application using bower you get countless of files you do not need. Think of

- Tags that aren't being imported
- README.md's and documentation in most `/bower_components/`
- Demo files in most `/bower_components/`

This doesn't matter if you're running it on a http server, but if you want to bundle it up as a packaged application it does become important. Now, with `vulcanize` it's possible to inline all the html tags, however the resultant file still has references like

```
<polymer-element [...] assetpath="bower_components/core-icon/">
```

Not really solving the issue at all thus. I have a hard time believing that I am the only one encountering this problem, so am I doing something wrong or what?

Comment: Vulcanize is currently the best approach we've got for this. The `assetpath` attributes are necessary in order to generate the right URLs for images/etc.  I'm a bit confused about the trouble you're having with it, though?

Comment: @Nevir: that the same directory also contains documentation and the like, something you do not want to distribute in an offline/local app.

Comment: Still confused, sorry: You _do_ want sources w/ documentation, but you just want any unused sources stripped out?

Comment: And if not: is `vulcanize --strip` not doing something you expect it to?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) to generate your production code. I have attached you one basic grunt config which will help you.

The script assumes the following grunt plugins:

```
    grunt-contrib-clean
    grunt-contrib-concat
    grunt-cssc
    grunt-dom-munger
    matchdep
```

Example grunt.js:

```
    module.exports = function (grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
            pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
            dom_munger: {
                read: {
                    options: {
                        read: [
                            {selector: 'link', attribute: 'href', writeto: 'CssRefs', isPath: true},
                            {selector: 'script[src]', attribute: 'src', writeto: 'JsRefs', isPath: true}
                        ]
                    },
                    src: 'src/index.html'
                },
                urlRewrite: {
                    options: {
                        remove: ['link', 'script'],
                        append: [
                            {selector: 'head', html: '<link href="style/screen.css" rel="stylesheet" />'},
                            {selector: 'body', html: '<script src="script/main.app"></script>'}
                        ]
                    },
                    src: ['dist/index.html']
                }
            },
            concat: {
                options: {
                    separator: ';'
                },
                dist: {
                    files: {
                        'dist/script/main.js': ['<%= dom_munger.data.JsRefs %>']
                    }
                }
            },
            cssc: {
                dist: {
                    options: {
                        sortSelectors: false,
                        lineBreaks: false,
                        sortDeclarations: false,
                        consolidateViaDeclarations: false,
                        consolidateViaSelectors: false,
                        consolidateMediaQueries: false
                    },
                    files: {
                        'dist/style/screen.css': ['<%= dom_munger.data.CssRefs %>']
                    }
                }
            },
            clean: {
                dist: {
                    src: ['dist']
                }
            }
        }
    );

//Load all required grunt plugins
    require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

//Custom Tasks
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['clean', 'dom_munger:read', 'concat', 'cssc', 'dom_munger:urlRewrite']);
};
```

This is just an basic example which you can extend for your needs.

Comment: This feels like... so much overkill and so... wrong. It feels like hacking your way out of the actual problem, as the real problem is the mixup of all the different kind of files (documentation, demos, actual production code)... Not to say that your solution might not actually be the best... Just a tad bit nervous about the added complexity for something that should be simple~.